# unittesting with ServletContextListener

Tags: spring, unit-testing, servlets, listener

i have an ServletContextListener which initializes my DB. and i've addid it in my web.xml:

```
<listener>
   <listener-class>util.MySessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

When i startup the server everything is fine.

but when i run my AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests-tests it is not called. what can i do?

Comment: Use http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/mock/web/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it with the

```
ApplicationContextAware
```

interface:

```
<bean id="springApplicationContext" class="server.utils.SpringApplicationContext" />
```

and in the

```
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
```

i can do my initialisation, hibernate and everything is ready at this point

Answer (score 10):

Is this [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) or [`HttpSessionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html)? Your naming is confusing.

Nevertheless, simply run this in `@Before`:

```
MockServletContext mockServletContext = new MockServletContext()
new MySessionListener().contextInitialized(
  new ServletContextEvent(mockServletContext)
)
```

Where [`MockServletContext`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockServletContext.html) comes from Spring. If your listener uses [`WebApplicationContextUtils`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/WebApplicationContextUtils.html), you will need to add this before running `contextInitialized()`:

```
mockServletContext.setAttribute(
  WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE, 
  yourTestApplicationContext
);
```

Where `yourTestApplicationContext` is an instance of `ApplicationContext` you can simply inject in your test case:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext yourTestApplicationContext;
```

Comment: when i call: new MySessionListener().contextInitialized(
  new ServletContextEvent(mockServletContext)
) , i get Context attribute is not of type WebApplicationContext

Comment: @wutzebaer probably too late now, but the value you set to the attribute doesn't look like an instance of  `WebApplicationContext`.